# Trace and debug PHP code

Tags: php

Can somebody tell me how can php code be traced on a distant webserver? I tried with xdebug but I cannot find php.ini and other configuration files?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If anything else fails there's always `var_dump` and `print_r` to use in your logic and follow what's going on. You've been very vague about what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: There are only like, 3 places it could be. I don't think you looked very hard (Googling for tutorials on PHP with your chosen distribution would help)

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the `remote debug` functionality in XDebug?

http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

You need an IDE that integrates with xdebug remote debug, like Netbeans 7.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Comment: I am now installing Netbeans, but I did not enable remote debug because I cannot find php.ini.

Comment: create a file on your web server called `phpinfo.php` in the document root with the code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then visit the url http://your-site.com/phpinfo.php and it will tell you where the `php.ini` file is on your server.